# socket() function error in C

Tags: c

I have a socket() function call in my code.(using C language):
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
I want that it should result in error.(INVALID_SOCKET)
Do we have some way out so that above function call results in error.
Like stopping some services,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say this is in your code, you could define your own implementation of `socket` that always returns INVALID_SOCKET:

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

If you link with the object file that defines your version of socket before linking with the real version, the linker will send all calls to `socket` to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create as many sockets as possible i.e. until it fails, then call your code. Or use #define to set the values of AF_INET and/or SOCK_STREAM to invalid values.

Comment: Do we any limit for socket creation ?